# default location for sqlite databases on an android device is not displaying my database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, bluetooth

I am a newbie to android. In my project i am sending data selected from drop down (spinners) via bluetooth.

I have created a database and loaded the values into spinners and sent the selected values via bluetooth. It is working fine .Now the problem is i know the database is created as i am displaying its values for the spinners. Now i want to  display the selected spinner data on submit in the form of a table.

I am not able to have a look at my already created database. say for eg. we have php myadmin in case of php to see and manipulate database. Is there something in android as such. I have already tried using Android device Monitor in DDMS and selecting data/data to find the database but it is not showing any databases. What may be the problem? It has to show something like com com.projectname inside data/data but it is not showing the same.

Comment: if you are looking for database of real device than its not possible, if you are running application in emulator than only you can see database in data/data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security purposes you cannot access the database directly on an Android device. But in case you are testing on an emulator you will be able to see the database from File explorer(Eclipse). Steps:

1. Go to to Window > Show View > Select File Explorer(in case its not there in the list click other at the bottom for more options).
2. Select File Explorer.
3. Your database will be there under **data** folder and your package name.
4. Pull the database file.
5. Install SQLite manager add-on in your browser.
6. Load your database file in it and you'll be able to see your complete database there.

In case your database is on an Android device, copy your database to another location in your SD card using the following code and then manually copy it from there on your PC and load that file in SQLite Manager.

```
/**
 * Export your database file
 */
private void exportDB() {

    String SAMPLE_PKG_NAME = "com.example.android";// your package name
    String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "database"; // your database name

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android";
    File sd = new File(path);
    if (sd.exists()) {
        Log.d("Database", "EXISTS");
    }
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/" + SAMPLE_PKG_NAME + "/databases/"
            + SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath + ".sqlite");
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```